# See difference between classifier and an image?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, classification

Let's say I've trained a classifier on a particular object, say Tom Cruise's face. If I then feed it an image of my own face, is there a way to see the *difference* between the classifier's representation and the image it was tested against?

(Not terribly important which library/language, but let's assume TensorFlow.)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you might define "difference" here, which will probably lead to different solutions. One simple one might be by looking at the last feature vector in the network before the classification and comparing it to some sort of "ideal" feature vector for Tom Cruise's face (though you'd probably have to do some sort of normalization on that vector as well so the values don't grow infinitely). Then you'd have some vector difference.

However, I'm guessing what you're actually looking for is seeing the difference *in image form*. But again, how you define "difference" might be a problem. I would suspect a good way of showing the difference, would be to show what should be changed in the image to make it look more like Tom Cruise. This is actually what the "Deep Dreaming" networks are (partially) about. The idea is that you compute the gradients, but then rather than looking at the gradients to the weights, you look at the gradients to the inputs. These are the values which, if you changed the image in that direction, would help you produce an image that looks more like your target class. It's as though your training is being used to update the image rather than the values of the network (after you already have a trained network that is).

A little more than halfway through [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgkfIQ4IGaM), you can see something similar to what I'm suggesting. They show what should change in the image for the network to respond more strongly to the given image.

Comment: Gotcha, definitely looking to see an image. My ML is pretty thin: "gradients to the inputs" means looking at the vectors of the model as compared to the image being tested?

Comment: @JeffThompson, When you normally train a network, you give an image to the network and ask it what's in it. You compare the result with the correct answer. Then use backpropagation to calculate the gradient for all weights (you test moving every weight slightly up and down to figure out what change would get you closer to the correct answer, but you use calculus so that you can figure it out for all variables at once). Then you would update the weights with those gradients to improve the network. In this case, you do the same thing, but figure out how you would change the image instead.

Comment: @JeffThompson, Actually though _you_ don't need to do most of this, since TensorFlow does most of this work for you. To get the gradients in TensorFlow (i.e. how the values should be changed to get to a better answer), you'll want to use [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients). Again, usually this (or a higher level function) is used to calculate gradients for the weights, but here, you want to use it for the changes on the image itself. There are several more details to make this work, but hopefully that gets you pointed in the right direction!